# HTML DIV TAG contents not visible in IE but when minimize it shows

Tags: html, css, jsp

My jsp code below is not visible in Internet Explorer browser 11 but when I minimize the browser I am able to view the Details in the center of the page. I feel that the div tag construction got the issue still not that much familiar using Div tag. Please  help on this.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %> 

<div class="commonMessage">File has been uploaded successfully.
    <form id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" action="/fileDownload.action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <ul>
           <li><label>File Name:</label><label class="longVal">${FileName}</label></li>
           <li><label>Content Type:</label><label class="longVal">${ContentType}</label></li>
           <li><label>Bat Ref:</label>${batRef}</li>
           <li><label>Total Records:</label>${totalRecordsCount}</li>
           <li><label>Error Records:</label>${totalErrorRecordsCount}</li>
                <s:hidden name="batRef"/>
                <%int errcount = (Integer)session.getAttribute("totalErrorRecordsCount");        
                // boolean showDLbutton = "upload".equals(invokeFrom);
            if (errcount !=0) {%>
                 <li><button type="submit" id="fileDownload" name="action:fileDownload" value="Submit" title="on" >Download .bad file</button></li>
            <%} %>
        </ul>
     </form>
     <p>Do you want to insert the records into the staging table?</p>
     <form id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" action="/fileUpload.action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <ul>
           <li>
              <button type="submit" id="fileConfirm" name="action:fileConfirm" value="Submit" title="on" >Yes</button><INPUT type= "button" value = "No" size = "number" title = "off" onclick="javascript:history.back(-1);"/>
            </li>
         </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: have you specified any CSS for this div class commonMessage

Comment: No I didn't specified CSS for the div class how to do please help on this

Comment: Sorry yes it is there .commonMessage {
 width: 480px;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 25px 0px 10px 110px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 11pt;
 font-weight: normal;
} but still not visible

Comment: do one thing , right click on you page and inspect element and see ,what is the height ,width and visiblity, and if any other parent elemnt trying to hide it or overlap it